# Best data type (in terms of speed/RAM) for millions of pairs of a single int paired with a batch (2 to 100) of ints

Tags: python, numpy

I have about 15 million pairs that consist of a single int, paired with a batch of (2 to 100) other ints.

If it makes a difference, the ints themselve range from 0 to 15 million.

I have considered using:

Pandas, storing the batches as python lists

Numpy, where the batch is stored as it's own numpy array (since numpy doesn't allow variable length rows in it's 2D data structures)

Python List of Lists.

I also looked at Tensorflow tfrecords but not too sure about this one.

I only have about 12 gbs of RAM. I will also be using to train over a machine learning algorithm so

Comment: What does this variable length batch represent?  My impression is that machine learning code usually expects 'fixed' size inputs - e.g. an array of M samples, with N features.  Or images all scaled to the same size.

Comment: A pandas dataframe or series with list elements uses object dtype.  You can also make an object dtype array that contains these lists (or arrays).  But computationally this is less efficient than a list of lists.  But just because you make such structures, doesn't mean you can use them in machine learning.

Comment: it's a list of possible labels, to be selected at random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
# create example data 
A = np.random.randint(0,15000000,100)                                      
B = [np.random.randint(0,15000000,k) for k in np.random.randint(2,101,100)]
```

`int32` is sufficient

```
A32 = A.astype(np.int32)
```

We want to glue all the batches together.
First, write down the batch sizes so we can separate them later.

```
from itertools import chain

sizes = np.fromiter(chain((0,),map(len,B)),np.int32,len(B)+1)
boundaries = sizes.cumsum()

# force int32
B_all = np.empty(boundaries[-1],np.int32)
np.concatenate(B,out=B_all)
```

After glueing resplit.

```
B32 = np.split(B_all, boundaries[1:-1])
```

Finally, make an array of pairs for convenience:

```
pairs = np.rec.fromarrays([A32,B32],names=["first","second"])
```

What was the point of glueing and then splitting again?

First, note that the resplit arrays are all views into `B_all`, so we do not waste much memory by having both. Also, if we modify either `B_all_` or `B32` (or rather some of its elements) in place the other one will be automatically updated as well.

The advantage of having `B_all` around is efficiency via numpy's `reduceat` ufunc method. If we wanted for example the means of all batches we could do `np.add.reduceat(B_all, boundaries[:-1]) / sizes` which is faster than looping through `pairs['second']`

Comment: Thanks! Why did you choose 'np.rec'? I'm not familiar with that type of array.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 It is a convenient way of creating mixed-type arrays allowing us to put single numbers and batches next to each other.

Comment: Do you know to get this structure if the data is in pandas dataframe? More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643236/1-column-has-an-int-another-has-a-list-of-ints-how-to-convert-dataframe-into-a/57643728#57643728

Comment: @PaulPanzer, you may want to revisit this answer.  It has sent the OP on a wild goose chase, with several follow on questions.  e.g. structured array vs record. best format for saving data, memory use in pandas vs numpy, usable inputs for machine learning (keras/torch).

Answer (score 2):

If you must store all values in memory, numpy will probably be the most efficient way. Pandas is built on top of numpy so it includes some overhead which you can avoid if you do not need any of the functionality that comes with pandas.

Numpy should have no memory issues when handling data of this size but another thing to consider, and this depends on how you will be using this data, is to use a generator to read from a file that has each pair on a new line. This would reduce memory usage significantly but would be slower than numpy for processing aggregate functions like sum() or max() and is more suitable if each value pair would be processed independently.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = (l for l in f)  # generator
        for line in data:
            # process each record here
```

Comment: How should I structure the numpy arrays? Should the single int be it's own numpy value, the batch be it's own numpy array, and then have another numpy array to hold the int/batch pairs in each of it's rows?

Comment: You can create a 2D Array where the first int in each array is your single int and the rest of the ints in the array are the paired set of ints. For example data = np.array([1,2884,28489,7328],[2,858628,83766284],[3,876,2395,192])

Comment: Does numpy strictly preserve the order? Is there any chance of the numbers being rearranged with save/append operations?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy. It us the most efficient and you can use it easily with a machine learning model.

Comment: Should the batch be it's own numpy array? Or is there a different method?

Comment: I don't think there is another method.