# Saving a numpy records file takes up more space if data are in numpy arrays, and less if the data are in lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data where in each row, one column is a single int, the other column is a batch of ints.

I heard the most speedy and RAM friendly datatype for this type of data are numpy records

[Best data type (in terms of speed/RAM) for millions of pairs of a single int paired with a batch (2 to 100) of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640595/best-data-type-in-terms-of-speed-ram-for-millions-of-pairs-of-a-single-int-pai)

because its a convenient way of creating mixed-type arrays allowing us to put single numbers and batches next to each other

But I accidentally discovered that if I save the data with the batches in a python list, it actually takes less memory than if the batch was converted to a numpy array. This is counter intuitive, because numpy was optimized for it's own data type; it would make No sense for it to have an easier time with a regular python list.

I am unable to generate a dataset example which replicates this result, this may be something unique to my data, but I am not sure what it is. When I try to replicate, having the batch as a list or numpy array saves to a same size disk file. ( if anyone could figure out what is unique about my data, and/or reproduce the error with randomly generated data, that would be amazing)

So for the minimal example, my data is need, below is a minimal example that downloads a small (~9mb) sample of my data, which creates the phenomenon.

For convenience, here is a colab notebook so anyone can play with the data without downloading to their system

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YB2mVNtBxu8Fr0oUXmtcNqT1KeIxktJm

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Download function for google drive 

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

#download the google drive file 
download_file_from_google_drive('1-0R28Yhdrq2QWQ-4MXHIZUdZG2WZK2qR', 'sample.pkl') 

#load df 
sampleDF = pd.read_pickle('sample.pkl')

# convert to numpy records 
firstNumRec = sampleDF.to_records(index=False)   

#save as batch in list form 
np.save( 'first.npy', firstNumRec)

#convert list to numpy array 
sampleDF['totalCites2'] = sampleDF['totalCites2'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

# convert to numpy records 
secondNumRec = sampleDF.to_records(index=False)   

# save as batch in numpy array form 
np.save( 'second.npy', secondNumRec)
```

The first file is 9.12 mb , the second is 10.22 mb, and most surprising of all, the pickle file is 8.52 mb. All of my data is in int form, so theoretically numpy should be most optimal to save this sort of data. Why is pickle able to pack this data into a smaller disk space?